# Login Auth in laravel customsize (SOLUTION)

Tags: laravel, authentication

Attempt to login in Laravel with custom data: num Id, TipoId, password Auth, but I always returns false, not to be configured to accept different data to email and password:

```
$tipoId=Input::get('tipoId');
$numId=input::get('numId');
$password=Input::get('password');


$userdata =  array('tipoId' => Input::get('tipoId'), 'numId' => Input::get('numId'), 'password' => Input::get('password')  );
if (Auth::attempt($userdata)) {

        }else{
            return $userdata;
        }
```

**Model**

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class Login extends Eloquent  implements UserInterface,   RemindableInterface{

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'Logins';


}
```

**Auth.php**

```
return array(

'driver' => 'eloquent',

'model' => 'Login',

'table' => 'Logins',

'reminder' => array(

    'email' => 'emails.auth.reminder',

    'table' => 'password_reminders',

    'expire' => 60,

),
```

Does not leave me any error but every time I try to login, I always returns false, not this doing wrong?

Comment: Is the password in your database hashed with `Hash::make()`?

Comment: yes    'password' => Hash::make('12345')

Comment: And is the password database field at least 60 characters long? (otherwise the hash get's truncated)

Comment: yes..       $2y$10$FQobU84gHR7ee5VfwUOHZuTFNd6UdLs/Izr9N

Comment: And there we have the problem. This hash is only 44 characters long, that almost certainly means it got truncated. Your database field for the password has to be **60 characters long**. Change that and update the hash.

Answer (score 0):

> $2y$10$FQobU84gHR7ee5VfwUOHZuTFNd6UdLs/Izr9N

And there we have the problem. This hash is only 44 characters long, that almost certainly means it got truncated. Your database field for the password has to be **60 characters long**. Change that and update the hash.